# ajax url path (root)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a website developed in ColdFusion and I use AJAX to do html requests (requests to ColdFusion Components). I'm having trouble with the AJAX URL path.

I'm calling the AJAX from my js located:

```
root/folder1/folder2/js/myJS.js
```

The AJAX is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: '/components/myComponent.cfc',
    data: {
        method:"ajaxTest",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
        console.debug(result);
    },
    error: function (error){
        console.debug('error');
  console.debug(error);
    }
});
```

My component is located:

```
root/components/myComponent.cfc
```

However, this AJAX request returns 404 Not Found. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: We really need more info. Have you tried using F12 tools to see the absolute URL (and params) that are being used from the browser?

Comment: You'll need to look at the network tab to see what URL is being hit, I suspect that will give you an answer as to what the absolute pathing is.

Comment: Don’t look at where the js is. Where is the page where the Ajax call is? In the root? Then just remove the leading /

Comment: Is the function `ajaxTest` a remote function?

Comment: Try to access that component directly via a browser without ajax. Can you get to it?